# Get a top level from Path object of pathlib

Tags: python-3.x, pathlib

I use `pathlib` to match all files recursively to filter the files based on their content. Then I would like to find what is the top level of the folder of this file. Assume the following. I have a file in the folder:

`a/b/c/file.log`

I do the search from the level `a`:

```
for f in path_data.glob("**/*"):
    if something inside file f:
         # I would like to get in what folder this file is, i.e. 'b'
```

I now that I can get all parents levels using:

- `f.parents` would give me `b/c`
- `f.parent` would give me `c`
- `f.name` would give me `file.log`

But how could I get `b`?

Just to precise: the number of levels where the file is stored is not known.

UPD: I know I could do it with split, but I would like to know if there is a proper API to do that. I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The question was asked a while ago, but didn't quite get the attention. Nevertheless, I still would publish the answer:

```
f.parts[0]
```